# Get the xml nodes where the search text is found

Tags: shell-script, files, xml

I having a well formatted and Indented xml similar to the below one. I need to get the mono tags which has a text " http://yahoo.com "

```
<root>
<mono id="1">
<tag1>http://google.com</tag1>
</mono>
<mono id="2">
<tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
</mono>
<mono id="3">
<tag1>http://mysite.com</tag1>
</mono>
<mono id="4">
<tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
</mono>
</root>
```

I was trying with the below command.

cat -n index.xml | sed -n "/root/,/root>/p" | grep "http://yahoo.com"

```
6  <tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
12  <tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
```

I need output like this.But don't know how to get the mono nodes which has my search text.

```
<mono id="2">
<tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
</mono>
<mono id="4">
<tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
</mono>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use `xsltproc` from `libxml2` toolkit to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//mono[tag1 = "http://yahoo.com"]' -nl file.xml
<mono id="2">
<tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
</mono><mono id="4">
<tag1>http://yahoo.com</tag1>
</mono>
```

The XPath `//mono[tag1 = "http://yahoo.com"]` means "any `mongo` node that has a sub-node called `tag1` whose value is `http://yahoo.com`".  The `-c` means "give me a copy of ..." and the final `-nl` inserts a newline at the end the output.

Would you want the `id` of the matching nodes:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//mono[tag1 = "http://yahoo.com"]/@id' -nl file.xml
```